# How to find all values for a specific key in pymongo?

Tags: python, json, mongodb

I have a mongoDB database that store several JSON files like this one :

```
{   "cmd": "VarReturn",
    "name": "temp",
    "result": 21.511440541411535,
    "coreInfo": {
      "last_app": "",
      "last_heard": "2016-01-18T18:41:29.559Z",
      "connected": true,
      "last_handshake_at": "2016-01-18T18:06:02.795Z",
      "deviceID": "X",
      "product_id": 6 
    } 
}
```

I want to query all values for `last_heard` and `result`, in order to get something like this :

```
last_heard = [2016-01-18T18:41:29.559Z, 2016-01-18T18:32:28.271Z, ...]

result = [21.511440541411535, 21.108604576216564, ...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **[`distinct()`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/1.4/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.distinct)** method:

```
last_heard = db.collection.distinct("coreInfo.last_heard")
result = db.collection.distinct("result")
```